# Github: can an issue be assigned to only a specific branch?

Tags: github

I'd like to add an issue to a repo in github, but only to a specific branch in the repo. Is that doable? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple answer: No.

Issues may be assigned to users, so they should take care of addressing them. You can only refer to code that is part of a branch by using the url.

However, nobody is stopping you from creating custom labels that reflect your branch structure. Might be useful for organizing issues into "production", "beta", "develop", ...

Sources: https://help.github.com/articles/about-issues/, https://guides.github.com/features/issues/ https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-label/, Using GitHub.